# Read bytes from a file, but they might be anywhere in the file (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net

I have a file that changes size depending on the amount of data it contains. With that, the location of the bytes that I want to read moves back and forth every time the file is saved by its main application. I am using the string inside the file "This is the data" to get close to the bytes I want to read `31 38 33 34`. They're always on the same position after the string, regardless of the size of the file. The only consistent thing is the string, the bytes will be different every time.

```
Try
    TextBuffer = File.ReadAllText("C:\test.txt")
Catch ex As Exception
    Exit Sub
End Try

Dim indexTar As Integer = TextBuffer.IndexOf("This is the data")
If indexTar >= 0 Then
    ListView1.Items.Add("This is the data")
End If
```

I use the code above to read the whole file and end up near the location where the bytes I want to read are.

[image]

How do I read those bytes `31 38 33 34`?

Comment: `file that changes size depending on the amount of data it contains` - that would be pretty normal for files...

Comment: Please do not ask the same question again. If the old question was closed you **must** edit the old one and try to get it reopened. Respect this site's resources and rules. If you are not sure how this site works I recommend reading [help]

Answer (score -1):

I'm not quite sure why you're talking about bytes, when this seems to be a text file - it would be easier to read and treat it as such, but simplistically you can read the whole thing into memory, find the index of what you know and then add some amount to get to the thing you don't:

```
Dim s = File.ReadAllText("C:\test.txt")
Dim indexTar = s.IndexOf("This is the data")

If indexTar >= 0 Then
    Dim tIdx = indexTar + "This is the data".Length + 4 'seems to be 4 bytes after the end of the string
    Dim iWantText = s.Substring(tIdx, 4)
End If
```

Now, `iWantText` contains `1834`. If you want it as a byte array, `Dim bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(iWantText)` will give it you.

It might be better, if the file is huge, to read it char by char (it will be buffered elsewhere, don't worry about inefficiency of reading one char at a time) looking for `T` and if you find it, see if `his is my data` follows...

Comment: Yeah, see my original question was flagged so I rewrote the question and an error snuck in. It's not a txt-file, sorry. It's a data file.

Comment: Doesn't mean it can't be searched, in either of the manners shown; text is just bytes.. it's just a matter of interpretation, and of what you want out of it. If you want to search as bytes, no problem; do file.readallbytes, indexof the T (0x54 / 84), then check if the bytes after are the `his is my data` ...